# ASP.NET Web API 2 - receiving a POST, but with no data

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to convert a WCF based REST server to ASP.NET Web API2. The existing WCF based one is:

```
public Message ProcessReportRequest(Stream inputStream) {
...
}
```

The client side is sending a byte[] (Java code below) and the client side cannot be changed as it is in use:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(encryptedByteData);
out.flush();
```

I've set up my controller as follows:

```
   public class LicenseController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("about")]
        public JsonResult<About> GetTest()
        {
            return Json(new About());
        }

        [Route("LicenseService.svc/v1/device")]
        public byte[] PostVer1Device(byte[] request)
        {
            Trap.trap();
            return request;
        }
}
```

If I get to localhost\about, the JSON comes back fine and fiddler shows the request and return.

When I call the Java code to post to localhost/LicenseService.svc/v1/device, It does call that method. But regardless of what I set as the parameter (byte[], object, string, Stream), the value of request is null. Also, Fiddler shows nothing, although that may be because it is waiting for the return before showing what is going on.

And no matter what I return, the stream read back from the response shows 0 bytes.

How do I get the data being posted to me? And how do I post data back?

thanks - dave

Comment: David can you compare the 2 fiddler requests? ie get a fiddler log for the old (working) request? especially look at the headers

Comment: The problem is Fiddler shows nothing for the new requests. My server app gets them (I have a breakpoint on them) but Fiddler shows nothing.

Comment: what is special about the new URL that would mean fiddler would not log them? are you sure you do not have filters enabled on fiddler that exclude the new URL? (what is the URL btw)